# Calling a JSP from Servlet with a dynamic Map

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm new to server side programming and I'm writing a simple servlet/jsp program.
The servlet part should get the parameters from the URL and save them to a map, and the jsp part should read the map and show its contents in an HTML table.

Here's the servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/RestaurantServlet86105511")
public class RestaurantServlet86105511 extends HttpServlet {
private static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
private String name;
private String price;

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    name = request.getParameter("name");
    price = request.getParameter("price");
    map.remove(name);
    map.put(name, price);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/RestaurantJSP86105511.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
public static HashMap<String, String> getMap() {
    return map;
}
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but after everytime rd.forward is called, the map contents will be deleted too and the jsp would only print the last parameters I've entered in the URL.
Is there any other way of calling a jsp from a servlet? or am I just doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Since every time `doGet()` is invoked, you are adding the `name` in the map which replaces the previous value associated with this key `name`. The `remove()` is reduntant in your case.

Comment: It's bad practice to have instance (or static) variables in Servlets since they are inherently not thread-safe. Learn MVC to structure your app.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is put your Map in to the request as an attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("yourMap", map);
```

Then in the JSP you can use JSTL and EL to access the values.

```
Price: ${yourMap.price}
Name: ${yourMap.name}
```